# How to determine unit cost?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm currently trying to study the formula for each of these questions.

This is the only page where you see in the picture in which I can't figure out how to calculate the numbers in order to get the answer.

Our books speaks about the formulas but I've tried every possible solution.

There is 3 other pages which I was able to solve just fine but I feel as if I missed an important step into figuring this out.

Here is an image of the questions: 
[image]

Comment: Your have to express the answer in the units they give you, they’re there in the far right. 600ml costing 2.4 is 0.6L, so cost per unit is 2.4/0.6L=7, for example

Comment: Which one you don't know? In any event `Unit cost` = `Cost` / `No of Unit`
e.g. a) water, you have `$3.80` / `2L` = `1.70 $/L`. 
In some case, you may need to convert the unit in final answer. 
e.g. b) pure vanilla extract `$4.20` / `600 mL` = `$4.20` / `0.6L` = `7.00 $/L`.

Comment: Everything after a and b weren't adding up correctly. I would take the AP Cost and divide it by No. of Units

Comment: An Example for c) and d), and then 1 Extension Price would be nice.

Comment: onion : `$5.12 / 34 lbs` = `$5.12 / (34 * 16 oz)` = `0.009411 $/oz`
black pepper : `$30.57 / 3 kg` = `30.57 / ( 3 * 2.20462 lbs)` = `4.62211 $/lbs`
So after round to 3 decimal place, the number for (c) is correct, the one for (d) looks like a typo. For the extension price, let's take salt as example, you want `1/4 tsp` * `1.54 $/fl oz` = `1/4 x 1/6 fl.oz` * `1.54 fl.oz` = `(1.54)/(4*6) $` = `0.0641666 $` rounding down to 3 decimal places, the supplied answer also looks correct. At the end, what you really need is a converter between different unit and I use google to do the conversion.

Comment: Thank you @achillehui I appreciate the help. I understand it more